# how to give two inputs to yolo darknet cfg files?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, config, yolo, darknet

I have developed a rgbd model for yolov2 tiny..So it requires two inputs rgb and depth ..feature extraction seperately and join the layer later..On using [route] I cannot get two inputs[image: This is the visual of my config file]

```
x = Conv2D(16, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', name='conv_1', use_bias=False)(input_image)
            self.convLayers+=1
            x = BatchNormalization(name='norm_1')(x)
            x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)
            Depthx = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

            x = Conv2D(16, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', name='conv_2', use_bias=False)(input_image)
            self.convLayers+=1
            x = BatchNormalization(name='norm_1')(x)
            x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)
            Rgbx = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)


            # Fuse Layer
            x = concatenate([Depthx, Rgbx])
            x=Conv2D(16, (1,1), strides=(1,1), padding='same', name='conv_3', use_bias=False)(x)
            self.convLayers+=1
            x = BatchNormalization(name='norm_1')(x)
            x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)
            x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
```

I need to write a config file for this model...Any kind of knowledge in config file writing is welcome
Thanks in advance